# react native app, error when building ios app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

In react native project, when building app for ios, getting the following error:

```
# XCode version: 13.2.1 #
# swift version: 5 #
## React native version: 0.69.4 (can't update project to latest react native version, because of some older dependency).


undef: _swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_swift_stdlib_isStackAllocationSafe", referenced from:
      function signature specialization <Arg[0] = [Closure Propagated : function signature specialization <Arg[1] = [Constant Propagated Function : closure #1 (__C.UIScene) -> Swift.Bool in (extension in StackProductPresentation):__C.UIApplication.topViewContoller.getter : Swift.Optional<__C.UIViewController>]> of reabstraction thunk helper from @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed __C.UIScene) -> (@unowned Swift.Bool, @error @owned Swift.Error) to @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed __C.UIScene) -> (@unowned Swift.Bool, @error @owned Swift.Error), Argument Types : []> of generic specialization <__C.UIScene> of Swift._NativeSet.filter((A) throws -> Swift.Bool) throws -> Swift._NativeSet<A> in StackProductPresentation(ProductPresenter.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: i found actually i am on react native latest version only. 0.69.4.